# Sorting geometric array in linear time without finding majority element

Tags: algorithms

It's an exercise I was given:
We say array of numbers $A$ is geometric if:

It has size $n=2^k-1$

It has $\log n$ distinct numbers

For each $0\leq i \leq k-1$ there exists an element in the array that appears exactly $2^i$ times.

 For example: $[8,5,2,5,5,5,8], k=3$
I need to sort the array in $\mathcal{O}(n)$ time and space.
I can solve it by using any algorithm that finds majority element in linear time.
My question is, can we solve it without finding using algorithm that finds majority element?

Comment: counting sort is the obvious answer.

Comment: Can you elaborate please?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort

Comment: If they are integers then count sort.  Unless the range is bigger than n it will be O(n) space.

Comment: We're happy to help you understand the concepts but just solving exercises for you is unlikely to achieve that. You might find [this page](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1284/755) helpful in improving your question.